# Switching 10 contacts with one switch

Tags: switches, relay, electromagnetism

I am looking for a way to switch 10 contacts but without having to switch these tiny contacts one after another. So basically one movement, 10 contacts open/close.
I saw this little switch: [image: switch]

But there I have to swtich them all. Unfortunately I didn't find anything useful in the Internet.

The LEDs on the schematic are there to check if the connections are good from connector to sockert and back. I want to check each socket(10) with this 10 LEDs. Is this possible with a Multiplexer (can you put current throught a Multiplexer?)

[image: Schematic]

I am grateful for any kind of help.
King regards

Comment: There are versions of those switches with 2 or 4 contacts per knob, but I'm not aware of versions with 10.

Comment: Define voltage and current. there are CMOS BCD Mux switches

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 Thanks for your answer. Vnom = 5V, Current per contact = 30 mA.

Comment: Is a jumper block feasible?

Comment: Why not 10 relays? then you could, if needed, operate them individually.

Comment: You mean one jumper for all the 10 contacts? Theretically, yes.

Comment: @SolarMike I also thought about that, but couldn't find a relay with 10 contacts.

Comment: I said 10 relays... not 1 relay with 10 contacts...

Comment: @SolarMike The problem is i need to switch 10 x 10 contacts. Sorry, I didn't point that out when asking the question.

Comment: 10 relays each controlling 10 relays...

Comment: 10 x 10?  So, 100 contacts?  I think it may be time to re-think your solution by explaining what exactly you are trying to do in your question.  So go make your question better!  It may be that the better solution has nothing to do with switches.

Comment: "*The problem is i need to switch 10 x 10 contacts.*" Your question explicitly states, "So basically one movement, 10 contacts open/close." Please fix your question.

Comment: You can get industrial-style pushbuttons that are modular, and you can stack as many contact blocks onto a single button as you like. The more contact blocks, the more difficult it will be to push the button, of course.

Comment: @SolarMike, why 10 relays? Bulky, expensive, unreliable and OP says all contacts are switched together.

Comment: @TonyM relays unreliable? seem to work fine - had to change 1 on my car out of around 30 and the car is 15 years old... some reliability... Bulky - possibly but that depends on the space available... Relays are used in **many** things, if they are as bad as you suggest why are they still made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many solutions. When you define cost and user interface, the choices get smaller...and smaller. When they go to 0, you change your specs'.

There are binary analog MUX and mechanical rotary MUX switches if you search harder.

Try [here](https://www.digikey.ca/products/en/switches/rotary-switches/200?k=&pkeyword=&sv=0&pv88=265&pv88=270&pv88=263&pv88=275&pv88=276&pv88=1081&pv88=1056&pv88=1085&pv88=1091&pv88=1086&pv88=1094&pv88=1061&pv88=1095&pv88=1062&pv88=1064&pv88=1046&pv88=1079&pv88=1065&pv88=1102&pv88=10&pv88=1067&pv88=1047&pv88=1051&pv88=1052&pv88=1048&pv88=1088&pv88=1106&pv88=1092&pv88=1078&pv88=1098&pv88=1099&pv88=1076&pv88=1090&pv88=1077&pv88=1069&pv88=1097&pv88=1068&pv88=11&pv88=30&pv88=31&pv88=32&pv88=12&pv88=33&pv88=13&pv88=34&pv88=1245&pv88=1243&pv88=1244&pv88=14&pv88=35&pv88=61&pv88=29&pv88=21&sf=1&FV=ffe000c8&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&pageSize=250) or [here](https://www.digikey.ca/en/product-highlight/t/texas-instruments/mux50x-analog-multiplexers?utm_adgroup=General&mkwid=s0hobsTmR&pcrid=87194106065&pkw=&pmt=b&pdv=t&productid=&slid=&gclid=Cj0KCQjwjYHpBRC4ARIsAI-3GkE4fCQyGYOvxP04CjC-Sf0sUxp7ll_g9-XyJsdg4XogqF1wIi9vRPwaAt4QEALw_wcB).

You might even consider a pot' controlled current with a transistor. But learn to start with a functional and interface spec'.  Better specs' mean a better design with more choices.